# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython' even though Cython is installed in Azure Devops

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-functions, requirements.txt

I'm setting up some CI/CD for a Python app (Azure Function) using Azure Devops and I've stumbled upon an issue with one of the requirements. The error I receive is **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'** while trying to install `pymssql-2.1.4`. Before this requirement, I have set a `Cython==0.29.21` to be installed and it is installed as it can be seen through out the logs as

```
Collecting Cython==0.29.21
  Downloading Cython-0.29.21-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (1.9 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.9/1.9 MB 73.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
```

I'm not sure why this error happens, I did some research and saw that it can be a problem with the `pip` version so I update the `pip` before doing the installation but the error keeps persisting. This is my yaml code for the part where I install the requirements.

```
python3 -m venv worker_venv
source worker_venv/bin/activate
python3 -m pip install pip --upgrade
pip3 install setuptools
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

I use python 3.8 version and ubuntu 20.04. Does somebody know how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it myself. In my case, for `pymssql-2.1.4`, I downgraded python to 3.7, downgraded pip to 20.0.2 and manually install `cython` before running the `pip install -r requirements.txt`. My new yaml now looks like

```
python3 -m venv worker_venv
source worker_venv/bin/activate
pip3 install pip==20.0.2
pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
pip3 install --upgrade cython
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

This did fix the problem and I no longer struggle with this kind of error. Posting this in case someone finds it useful